# Where is the correct place to handle common functions in a Terraform provider?

Tags: terraform

I haven't used Terraform or Go before but for work am teaching myself so I can work on a provider we're making. So far I think most of the pieces of the puzzle make sense but one piece I haven't figured out is where to put common functions.

In the Hashicups example they have a folder in `/vendor/github.com/hashicorp-demoapp/hashicups-client-go/` which has all their common code. My Duck-Duck-Go-fu (doesn't have the same ring to it does it?) failed me. I understand that folder is made from `go mod vendor` but I'm making an in-house provider so I don't have a vendor folder.

If I have functions common to several resources where is the correct place to put those? Do I just make a `common.go` file and put it with the rest of the resources in my `<provisioner_name>` folder?

Comment: This is really more a Golang question than Terraform question (and also opinion based), but you can peruse major providers to see how their Go utility functions are commonly organized.

Comment: @MattSchuchard ah ok - so GoLang doesn't have an official recommendation from a style guide or something? Basically just do something that makes sense?

Comment: There are no real best practices guidelines for the Terraform provider+Golang situation with common functions. Consulting the major providers for their design patterns is your best bet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hashicups-go-client is actually the Go client for interacting with the Hashicups web API. The Terraform docs recommend that you split out the actual web API client from the Terraform provider. Then, ideally, you end up with the situation as shown:

```
terraform-core <-> terraform-provider <-> web-api-go-client <-> web-api
```

You can of course just bundle everything into the terraform provider, but this is not recommended. The go-client should be completely standalone and robust.

So to answer the question - if the functions are related to Terraform functionality, they should live in your Terraform provider package. If they interact with the web API, split them off into a separate Go client package, and use this package in your Terraform provider to interact with the web API.